# Using GPU with Tensorflow in Linux VirtualBox VM on Windows10

Tags: virtualbox, gpu

I found some details in the answers to this question [Using NVidia GPU from VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/779070/use-nvidia-gpu-from-virtualbox). But these address a different problem. I could not figure out if there is any possibility of using an NVIDIA GPU from a Linux VirtualBox VM for Training models in Tensorflow 2.0 and above.
I know about the possibilities of using dual boot or Windows version of Tensorflow. But my problem is that i want to use some packages related to Tensorflow which are not yet supported on Windows. And i am not able to get a separate Linux machine at work as of now. Also switching completely to Linux on my machine is not an option. WSL does not support use of GPU. I am hesitant to use [Windows Insider Program build](https://insider.windows.com/en-us/getting-started/)
Please provide any suggestions if possible (including (if you are confident) the suggestion to just give up till Microsoft and Nvidia solve this amongst themselves).

Comment: [Sorry, refering to Virtualbox hasn't any GPU direct access feature.](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=97874&p=474787&hilit=direct+gpu+access#p474787)